# How to customize yadcf plugin to pass my own items in the filter

Tags: yadcf

I am trying to use yadcf plugin for multiselect plugin in my datatable since it is flexible to use.It generates dropdown multiselect filter with values available in perticular row.  I want to customize this in such a way to pass my own list and values corresponding to same like (list)but not getting how can i do this. If anyone could guide me in this, I will be grateful for you.

```
{    
    column_number: 1,
    filter_type: "multi_select",
    select_type: 'select2',
    filter_reset_button_text: false
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [data](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/3db921a674f785af22d436b2676e8bf04c07004a/src/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L47) property

For example

```
{    
    column_number: 1,
    filter_type: "multi_select",
    select_type: 'select2',
    filter_reset_button_text: false,
    data: ["value1","value2"]
}
```

Here is small fragment from the docs (you better read more in order to know about yadcf feature)

```
* data
                Required:           false
                Type:               Array (of string or objects)
                Description:        When the need of predefined data for filter is needed just use an array of strings ["value1","value2"....] (supported in select / multi_select / auto_complete filters) or
                                    array of objects [{value: 'Some Data 1', label: 'One'}, {value: 'Some Data 3', label: 'Three'}] (supported in select / multi_select filters)
                Note:               that when filter_type is custom_func / multi_select_custom_func this array will populate the custom filter select element
*
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for the response. I am trying to understand this. for ex: <option value="a"|"b">name</option> i want to create filter like the above means, it will be done as "data:[{ value:"a","b", label:'name'}]" . Am i right?

Comment: Not sure how it will behave with `|` in the value (escaping / etc') start with value="a" and proceed from there

Comment: This plugin is really good. Is there any way that I can pass more than one value for ex. something like  data:[{value: ['Some Data 1','Some Data 2'], label: 'One'}] ?

Comment: you can do something like this data:: [{value: ['Some Data'], label: 'Some Data'}], filter_match_mode: 'contains' , read docs - https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/3db921a674f785af22d436b2676e8bf04c07004a/src/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L187 , you can also use regular expressions, try it and try googling this

Comment: Thganks again. But i need to pass multiple values in value attribute.

Comment: you can also use the `filter_type: 'custom_func',`  or `multi_select_custom_func` see showcase http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_source.html (first column) , read docs for more info